# Angular2-PrimeNg - Reactive forms - Multiselect does not work

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeNg - 2.0.3 and Angular 2.0.0 I am using reactive forms. I want to use the multiselect feature of PrimeNg in my form. I have done the following

Component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
       <label for="cities" class="control-label">Cities</label>
        <p-multiSelect [options]="cities" formControlName="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
 </div>
```

Component.ts

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

export class CreateKMSControlComponent implements OnInit {
    cities: SelectItem[];
    selectedCities: FormControl;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.cities = [];
            this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:'New York'});
            this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:'Rome'});
            this.cities.push({label:'London', value:'London'});
            this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:'Istanbul'});
            this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:'Paris'});
    }
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({ 
        selectedCities : this.selectedCities
    })
}
```

But I get an error Error :  trying to diff ' ' Not sure what needs to be done to fix this problem. Can someone guide us.

Comment: Update the packages to latest version. And Check

Answer (score 0):

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng';

export class CreateKMSControlComponent implements OnInit {
    cities: SelectItem[];
    selectedCities: FormControl;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.cities = [];
        this.cities.push({label:'New York', value:'New York'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Rome', value:'Rome'});
        this.cities.push({label:'London', value:'London'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Istanbul', value:'Istanbul'});
        this.cities.push({label:'Paris', value:'Paris'});

        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({ 
          selectedCities : this.selectedCities
       });
    }
}
```

change initializing your form into the `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: how `selectedCities` is instantiated?